# Always show div on mobile version

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to show the "info" div (the black box with the white text, that gets visible on mouse hover on the image), but ONLY on mobile and WITHOUT the hover effect.

Tried the following way:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) 
{
    .image-hover-page-container.animatedParent.info{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

my site: [link](https://www.atvmototraveler.ro/trasee/)
source code: [link](https://pastebin.com/CRHMcZB1)

Comment: Are you looking for CSS-only solution? CSS-only solution would rely only on screen breakpoints and you'd be relying on screen sizes. Targeting browsers might work better, but would require some Javascript.

Comment: Please share more details. Is this really a problem related to PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For show on mobile, add these elements to active CSS file:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    }
    .ih-item.square.effect3.bottom_to_top .img {
        transform: translateY(-50px) !important;
    }
    
    .ih-item.square.effect3.bottom_to_top .info {
        transform: translateY(0) !important;
        visibility: visible; 
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help - it works, BUT the text is not displayed

Comment: Pls. accept my response )

Comment: I will change my response one minute pls

Comment: I changed my codes. Please check and come back to me